# How to highlight specific code lines in a .qmd html file

Tags: html, r, quarto

Has someone found a way to highlight specific code lines in quarto html documents (similar to the reveal.js code highlighting option?). For instance, in the following example I would like to highlight the newly added `group_by()` code line:

````
---
format: html
---

```{r}
library(dplyr)
iris |> 
  summarize(mean(Sepal.Length))
```

Add `group_by()`:

```{r}
iris |> 
  group_by(Species) |> 
  summarize(mean(Sepal.Length))
```
````

I found [this package](https://r-for-educators.github.io/flair/index.html) which, however, only works for RMarkdown. Any hints are much appreciated! :)

Comment: Can't you use the reveal.js quarto presentation, since it outputs an HTML file anyway?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't :(

Comment: Discussed a bit here: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/2987 (summary: not possible for now)

Comment: I've seen that, but I hoped for a workaround :)

Comment: @bretauv, I have found out a possibility! (see my answer). Would appreciate any feedback. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a small Quarto filter extension [`line-highlight`](https://github.com/shafayetShafee/line-highlight) to enable line highlighting (both for source code and output) in HTML output format (i.e. `format: html`).

To highlight a specific line of source code, you need to use the chunk option `source-line-numbers` which takes values similarly as [`code-line-numbers`](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/html.html#code). **Note that, this filter extension requires Quarto v1.2 at least to work.**

So in your given example, to highlight the newly added `group_by()` code line, we can do the following (additionally, we can use `class-source: "numberLines"` to enable source code chunk line numbering),

````
---
format: html
filters: 
  - line-highlight
---


```{r}
#| message: false
#| source-line-numbers: "4"

library(dplyr)

iris |> 
  group_by(Species) |> 
  summarize(mean(Sepal.Length))
```


```{r}
#| class-source: "numberLines"
#| source-line-numbers: "2"

iris |> 
  group_by(Species) |> 
  summarize(mean(Sepal.Length))
```
````

---

[image: line highlighting]

---

See the [github repository](https://github.com/shafayetShafee/line-highlight#line-highlight-extension-for-quarto) for more examples and the installation process.

Comment: Great work, thank you so much!

Comment: @Julian,   I'd like to know about the edge cases where this breaks :)